# How to create a large sparse block matrix

Tags: linear-algebra, sparse-arrays, expression-construction

I need to generate a very large sparse block matrix, with blocks consisting only of ones along the diagonal. I have tried several ways of doing this, but I seem to always run out of memory.

The fastest way of doing this that I've come up with so far is as follows:

(typically, I will need `n` to be at least 2500 and m of the order 50).

```
tmp= SparseArray[{}, {n,n}, 1];

SparseArray@
 ArrayFlatten@
  Table[If[i == j, tmp, 0], {i, m}, {j, m}]
```

Example when n=2, m=4:

[image: Matrix]

The problem with this construction is that `ArrayFlatten` for some reason converts the result to a normal matrix, and I run out of memory. That is, when it works, this code computes the end result very quickly and the result does not take up much memory. At some specific number however, it suddenly crashes as the intermediate `ArrayFlatten` step clogs up the memory.

Any help will be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 10):

Maybe this ?

```
SparseArray[{Band[{1, 1}, Dimensions[tmp] {m, m}] -> {tmp}}, Dimensions[tmp] {m, m}]
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, this seems to solve the issue!

Answer (score 3):

I think [`KroneckerProduct`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/KroneckerProduct) is the right tool for this question:

```
kp[n_,m_] := KroneckerProduct[
    SparseArray[IdentityMatrix[m]],
    SparseArray[SparseArray[{}, {n,n}, 1], Automatic, 0]
]
```

Note that I convert the [`SparseArray`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/SparseArray) in the second argument into a [`SparseArray`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/SparseArray) that has `0` as the default element. Otherwise, the output of [`KroneckerProduct`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/KroneckerProduct) is no longer a [`SparseArray`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/SparseArray) object. Here is Mr.Wizard's last suggestion:

```
fn[n_,m_] := SparseArray[
    Tuples[Range@# - {1,0,0}] . {Rest@#, {1,0},{0,1}}&@{m,n,n} -> 1
]
```

And a comparison:

```
r1 = fn[300, 20]; //MaxMemoryUsed //AbsoluteTiming
r2 = kp[300, 20]; //MaxMemoryUsed //AbsoluteTiming
r1 === r2
```

> {0.959416, 379069184}
>
> {0.023961, 59095360}
>
> True

Comment: I bow to the the master. :-)  I didn't even realize KroneckerProduct could be used this way, much less how to optimize it as you did.  Thank you, again, for lending your expertise to this community.  Are you able to provide any additional insight into why this outperforms `SparseArray[Band[{1, 1}] -> SparseArray[{}, {m, n, n}, 1]];]` to such a great degree?

Comment: @Mr.Wizard My guess is that "unsparsing" is occurring, i.e., the `SparseArray` in the `Band` is getting converted to a normal matrix under the hood.

Comment: For what it's worth I think `IdentityMatrix[m, SparseArray]` is superior to `SparseArray[IdentityMatrix[m]]`

Comment: Agreed, that is nicer!

Answer (score 2):

I find that this performs equivalently to b.gatessucks' code while being significantly cleaner.

```
n = 3;
m = 2;

SparseArray[Band[{1, 1}] -> SparseArray[{}, {m, n, n}, 1]]
```

$\left(
\begin{array}{cccccc}
 1 & 1 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
 1 & 1 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
 1 & 1 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 1 & 1 \\
 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 1 & 1 \\
 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 1 & 1 \\
\end{array}
\right)$

However [`ArrayFlatten`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/ArrayFlatten.html) is still worth your consideration.  Using a modified form of a method I posted for this slightly more general Q&A [How to form a block-diagonal Matrix from a list of matrices?](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/19778/121):

```
IdentityMatrix[m] /. {1 -> SparseArray[{}, {n, n}, 1]} // ArrayFlatten

(* same output as above, but not a SparseArray *)
```

In cases were n >> m (as described in the question) the peak memory consumption is actually not much more, it is easily an order of magnitude faster, and conversion into a sparse array is very fast:

```
{n, m} = {300, 20};

MaxMemoryUsed[
  r1 = SparseArray[Band[{1, 1}] -> SparseArray[{}, {m, n, n}, 1]];] // AbsoluteTiming

MaxMemoryUsed[
  r2 = IdentityMatrix[m] /. {1 -> SparseArray[{}, {n, n}, 1]} // 
     ArrayFlatten;] // AbsoluteTiming

r1 == r2

SparseArray[r2]; // RepeatedTiming
```

> ```
> {3.37077, 459439920}
>
> {0.13651, 576105096}
>
> True
>
> {0.091, Null}
> ```

For optimal memory performance a variation of ybeltukov's `blockArray` from [Speeding up generation of block diagonal matrix](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/99467/121#99468) surpasses both methods:

```
fn[n_, m_] := 
  SparseArray[Tuples[Range@# - {1, 0, 0}].{Rest@#, {1, 0}, {0, 1}} &@{m, n, n} -> 1]

MaxMemoryUsed[r3 = fn[300, 20];] // RepeatedTiming

r1 == r3
```

> ```
> {0.769, 379069184}
>
> True
> ```