# How to form a block-diagonal matrix from a list of matrices?

Tags: matrix, expression-construction

For example, like this:

[image]

I know `Join` works, but it is a bit troublesome for multiple matrices. I also tried `DiagonalMatrix`, but it can only form a matrix from a list of elements.

Comment: Have a look at `ArrayFlatten`.

Comment: @Mr.Wizard, thanks.

Comment: Related: [(18224)](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/18224/121)

Answer (score 68, accepted):

[ybeltukov](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/users/4678/ybeltukov)'s `blockArray` from [Speeding up generation of block diagonal matrix](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/99467/121#99468) blows the methods below out of the water by orders of magnitude, in terms of performance.

---

```
a = {{1, 2, 3}, {4, 5, 6}, {7, 8, 9}};

b = {{1, 2}, {3, 4}};

ArrayFlatten[{{a, 0}, {0, b}}] // MatrixForm
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

You can `Fold` this operation over a list of matrices to get a diagonal:

```
a = {{1, 2, 3}, {4, 5, 6}, {7, 8, 9}};
b = {{1, 2}, {3, 4}};
c = {{1, 2, 3}, {4, 5, 6}};
d = {{1, 2}, {3, 4}, {5, 6}};

Fold[ArrayFlatten[{{#, 0}, {0, #2}}] &, a, {b, c, d}] // MatrixForm
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Here is another way to do this, illustrating a forcing of `DiagonalMatrix` by using an arbitrary head (`Hold`) on top of `List`:

```
DiagonalMatrix[Hold /@ {a, b, c, d}] // ReleaseHold // ArrayFlatten // MatrixForm
```

> (same output)

Or a bit more cleanly using `Unevaluated` (though this may be harder to apply in a program as opposed to interactive input because the elements of your matrix list will probably not be named):

```
DiagonalMatrix[Unevaluated @ {a, b, c, d}] // ArrayFlatten // MatrixForm
```

> (same output)

Comment: Mr.Wizard What about a list of Matrices? I only examplified two matrices to form one block-diagonal matrix. Better automatic method.

Comment: @user5463 what do you mean?

Comment: Suppose my matrices are not predefined, but generated in the middle of my program.

Comment: @user5463 see my updated answer; is that what you want?

Comment: @user5463 You're welcome.  I added a second method I think you will find interesting.

Comment: @Mr.Wizard, it's been a while since I used `ArrayFlatten` but if I remember correctly it uses quite a bit of memory and was somewhat slow for large matrices.

Comment: @ruebenko `ArrayFlatten` is [best for packed arrays](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/7997/121) and slower otherwise.  I cannot recall it being a memory hog though of course I expect a `SparseArray` to be much better there.

Comment: @Mr.Wizard, yea, I think I tried `ArrayFlatten` with `SparseArray` and that did not work to well memory wise. If I recall correctly, the best was to create an empty `SparseArray` and then set the respective parts. If you ever come across an example where this is an issue let me know. Thanks any ways.

Comment: I have to say your `Fold` and `Unevaluated` make me shine at the moment.Can you give a same amazing solution in [this topic](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/120433/21532) about the opposite operation of you? :)

Comment: @yode I saw that question when it was posted and nothing useful came to mind.  However your use of `"BoundingBoxes"` is great!  So thanks for the kind words but you've surely outdone me this time. :-)

Comment: @Mr.Wizard Brilliant answer. Thanks a lot. But why the last 'Unevaluated' one doesn't work if we replace {a,b,c,d} by something like Table{a,4}? However, the 'Hold' one works.

Comment: @huotuichang Let me see if I can explain in a comment.  `Diagonal` needs to "see" a simple vector (list) of elements (i.e. not matrices themselves) for it to work in the manner I need here.  `Unevaluated @ {a, b, c, d}` works because `{a, b, c, d}` is expressly a vector of elements, and `Unevaluated` keeps the evaluator from changing it before `Diagonal` "sees" it.  However `Table[. . .]` *is not* expressly a vector and therefore `Diagonal` doesn't know how to operate on it.  This is what I meant by "may be harder to apply in a program." (continued)

Comment: `Hold /@ Table[. . .]` should work because first the `Table` evaluates, then `Hold` wraps each individual element making `Diagonal` "see" a simple vector even if elements (now wrapped in `Hold`) are themselves deeper arrays..

Comment: @Mr.Wizard Thank you for the clarification!

Answer (score 39):

**Update:** Just bumped into this: `` SparseArray`SparseBlockMatrix ``:

```
bmF = With[{r = MapIndexed[#2[[1]] {1, 1}-># &, #, 1]}, SparseArray`SparseBlockMatrix[r]]&;

a = {{1, 2, 3}, {4, 5, 6}, {7, 8, 9}};
b = {{1, 2}, {3, 4}};
c = {{x, y, z}, {u, v, w}};

bmF[{a, b, c}]  // MatrixForm
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

**Original post:**

```
 diagF = With[{dims = Total@(Dimensions /@ {##})}, 
    SparseArray[Band[{1, 1}, dims] -> {##}, dims]] &;
```

Edit: Much more elegant form (thanks to Mr.Wizard)

```
 diagF = SparseArray[Band[{1, 1}] -> {##}] &
```

Example:

```
 a = {{1, 2, 3}, {4, 5, 6}, {7, 8, 9}};
 b = {{1, 2}, {3, 4}};
 c = {{1, 2, 3}, {4, 5, 6}};
 d = {{1, 2}, {3, 4}, {5, 6}};
 diagF[a, b, d, b, c] // MatrixForm
```

[image]

Comment: I forgot about that. Nice.

Comment: If I am not mistaken this function can be reduced to: `diagF = SparseArray[Band[{1, 1}] -> {##}] &`

Comment: @Mr.Wizard, you are right! (somehow I did not get that form working when I first tried; need to use `ClearAll` more often.)

Comment: +1 Great solution.  It may be worth pointing out, though, that the example is *not* a block-diagonal matrix. By definition, a block-diagonal matrix represents an endomorphism of a product of vector spaces in which each component space is mapped to itself; ergo, *the blocks must be square.*  But it is evident that this solution will work correctly when its input matrices are all square; it can be thought of as a generalization of the block-diagonal form in which the matrix represents a Cartesian product of arbitrary linear maps (rather than just endomorphisms).

Comment: @whuber, thanks. Great observation.

Comment: @kguler  diagF fails when I'm running diagF[{0, 1, 0}, {1, 0, 0}]. Is it because Mathematica treat row vector and column vector the same way?

Comment: @user5463, what is the expected output from  `diagF[{0, 1, 0}, {1, 0, 0}]`? Does `diagF[{{0, 1, 0}}, {{1, 0, 0}}]` give what is expected?

Comment: MatrixForm[SparseArray[Automatic, {6, 
   2}, 0, {1, {{0, 0, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2}, 
     {{1}, {2}}}, {1, 1}}]]   is what i want.

Comment: @user5463, you can use `diagF[{{0}, {1}, {0}}, {{1}, {0}, {0}}]` or `diagF[Transpose@{{0, 1, 0}}, Transpose@{{1, 0, 0}}]` to get column matrices on the "diagonal".

Comment: @kguler Yes that is what i want, but I'm wondering why diagF fails in this case.

Comment: @user5463, each argument to `diagF` need to be a 2d array (in other words, `ArrayDepth[argi]` needs to be 2 for each array `argi` in the argument sequence).

Comment: @kguler I noticed that, I want to rewritie diagF[] to include the 1d list situation, Any advice?

Comment: @user5463, if you want to use mixtures of  `kX1`, `1Xm` and `nXp` arrays as input the  most convenient way I can think of is the current form of diagF: for example, `diagF[(* a 3X1 array *){{x}, {y}, {z}},(* a 2X3 array *){{a, b,  c}, {d, e, f}},(* and a 1X3 array *){{r, s, t}}]`.

Comment: ... or, if you wish to get a version that takes only columns as input you can define `diagColF = diagF @@ (List /@ # & /@ {##}) &` and use as `diagColF[{0, 1, 0}, {1, 0, 0}]`. Similarly, define `diagRowF = diagF @@ (List /@ {##}) &` for  a version that takes rows as input and use as `diagRowF[{0, 1, 0}, {1, 0, 0}]`. Hope this helps.

Comment: What's wrong with `CirclePlus := SparseArray[Band[{1, 1}] -> {##}] &; a_\[CirclePlus]b_ := CirclePlus[a, b]`

Comment: Hi, kglr. It fails for sparse block. For a fix, `diagF = SparseArray[Band[{1, 1}] -> Normal /@ {##}] &`

Comment: @matheorem, it may be a version problem -- In version 9 it works when `a,b,c,d` are `SparseArray`s.

Comment: Oops, I am wrong. It is working for SparseArray, while not working for `SymmetrizedArray` type. Check it again : )

Answer (score 3):

---

```
a = {{1, 2, 3}, {4, 5, 6}, {7, 8, 9}};

b = {{1, 2}, {3, 4}}; SparseArray[Band[{1, 1}] -> {a, b}] // MatrixForm
```

[image]