# Create a matrix of matrices using Band and ArrayFlatten

Tags: matrix, list-manipulation, sparse-arrays

I can easily write a simple Band matrix using:

```
SparseArray[{Band[{2, 1}] -> a}, {Dim, Dim}]
```

where `a` is a number.

Now, I would use the same method to build a block matrix, using a matrix in place of variable `a`. The block matrix would then be flatten with `ArrayFlatten`.

The line above does not work, I receive an error regarding a mismatch of dimensions.

I don't want to use something like `ArrayFlatten[{{M1, M2}, {M3, M4}}]`, explicitly inserting each matrix, `M1, M2, ...`, as I expect to need bigger block matrices.

Can someone tell me how to work it out?

Comment: related [Q/A](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/19778/125)

Comment: @kguler In fact that seems like a duplicate.  Do you disagree?

Comment: @Mr.W, you are right; perhaps altroware can clarify if/why it is not.

Comment: That question refers to a diagonal block matrix. However, the function `Fold` could be useful in a more general case. I'm doing some trials.

Comment: No, I don't think this helps. I need something like `Band`. In am not interested in the diagonal but in the lower (upper) digonal band.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It looks to me like you need [`KroneckerProduct`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/KroneckerProduct.html). I'll define all matrices as `SparseArray` below, with the band matrix having only `1`s on the off-diagonal. Then `KroneckerProduct` inserts the desired matrix `insertMatrix` where the `1` appeared in the original matrix. The result is also a `SparseMatrix`, so I apply `Normal` to show the final structure:

```
baseMatrix = SparseArray[{Band[{2, 1}] -> 1}, {4, 4}];

insertMatrix = SparseArray@Array[Subscript[a, ##] &, {4, 2}];

blockMatrix = KroneckerProduct[baseMatrix, insertMatrix];

Normal[blockMatrix] // MatrixForm
```

[image: matrix]

You can generalize this by constructing a more complicated matrix as a sum of `KroneckerProducts`.

Answer (score 5):

**Update:** With a loose interpretation of the comment by the OP

> I need something like Band. In am not interested in the diagonal but in the lower (upper) diagonal band.

the following simple modification of [this answer](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/19780/125) gives

a "pseudo-lower-diagonal band" starting from position `{2,1}`:

```
SparseArray[Band[{2, 1}] -> matrices] // Normal // MatrixForm
```

[image]

and a "pseudo-upper-diagonal band" starting from position `{1,3}`:

```
SparseArray[Band[{1, 3}] -> matrices] // Normal // MatrixForm
```

[image]

---

**Original post:**

Perhaps something like the following is what you need:

You have a number of matrices, say four of them, `a, b, c, d` (styled  for later use):

```
matrices = {Array[Style[Subscript[a, #1, #2], Red, Bold, 16] &, {2, 3}], 
   Array[Style[Subscript[b, #1, #2], Blue, Bold, 16] &, {3, 2}], 
   Array[Style[Subscript[c, #1, #2], Green, Bold, 16] &, {2, 2}], 
   Array[Style[Subscript[d, #1, #2], Orange, Bold, 16] &, {3, 3}]};
MatrixForm /@ matrices
```

[image]

and the same number of starting positions

```
starts = RandomInteger[{1, 10}, {4, 2}] (* ignoring the possible overlaps *)
(* {{3,3},{10,3},{7,9},{6,7}} *)
```

and you want to place the matrices in a sparse array with the above starting positions:

```
sa = SparseArray[Band[#] -> #2 & @@@ Transpose[{starts, matrices}]];
```

This is what `sa` looks like:

```
sa // Normal // MatrixForm
```

[image]

Comment: Yes, your interpretation was right.It is great, Band can still be used with block matrices, but we have to give the whole sequence of matrices `{a,a,...}` instead of just `a`.