# How to create a block diagonal matrix by repeating a submatrix $n$ times?

Tags: matrix

If there is a submatrix, let's call $P$:

$P=\begin{pmatrix} 1 & 1 \\ 1 & 1 \end{pmatrix}$

And I want to have $n$, let's say $n=2$, such submatrices placed on the diagonal. The result is expected to look like:

$Q=\begin{pmatrix} 1 & 1 & 0 & 0 \\ 1 & 1 & 0 & 0 \\ 0 & 0 & 1 & 1 \\ 0 & 0 & 1 & 1 \end{pmatrix}$

How do I write the code in Mathematica?

Comment: This seems to be a special case of this question: [How to form a block-diagonal Matrix from a list of matrices?](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/19778)

Comment: I noticed that thread. Well, it didn't say how to do that $n$ times.

Comment: Mainly I was just linking the question -- see "Linked" in column on the right -- so that others might easily find it.  Some of the answers there are easily adapted (using `ConstantArray[P, n]` for the list of matrices), but special cases often also have special solutions.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
f1 = KroneckerProduct[IdentityMatrix[#], #2]& 
f2 = SparseArray[{Band[{1, 1}, # Dimensions@#2] -> {#2}}] &
f3 = SparseArray[{Band[{1, 1}] -> ConstantArray[#2, #]}] &
f4 = ArrayFlatten[IdentityMatrix[#] /. 1 -> #2 ] &

p = Table[1, {2}, {2}];
f1[3, p]
f2[3, p] // Normal
f3[3, p] // Normal
f4[3, p]
```

all give

```
(* {{1,1,0,0,0,0},{1,1,0,0,0,0},
    {0,0,1,1,0,0},{0,0,1,1,0,0},
    {0,0,0,0,1,1},{0,0,0,0,1,1}} *)
```

Comment: I posted basically the same thing [here](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/49330/245), but unfortunately the thread got closed.

Comment: @Jens, yes these are special cases of the answers in that Q/a and in [the one linked there](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/19778).

Answer (score 5):

```
mat[p_, n_] := ArrayFlatten[DiagonalMatrix[Array[1 &, n]] /. {1 -> p, 0 -> 0 p}]
p = {{1, 2}, {3, 1}};
mat[p, 3] // MatrixPlot
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Comment: I'm slowly deleting my nearly identical answer now sobbing softly.

Comment: @kale Soooo sorry :)

Answer (score 4):

Also useful here would be the Outer product:

```
p = ConstantArray[1, {2, 2}];
ArrayFlatten[Outer[Times, IdentityMatrix[2], p]]
```

which gives the desired output (displayed using MatrixForm)

[image]