# How to use Array[] to evaluate block-diagonal matrix at different values

Tags: matrix

I would like to construct a diagonal matrix that is defined as a function and put it multiple times in a block-diagonal matrix each block evaluated at a consecutive integer.

Let's say my matrix looks like this:

$$\mathtt{mat}[x\_]=\begin{pmatrix} 
x & 1 \\
1 & x^2 
\end{pmatrix}$$

and I would like to stack it up such that it looks something like this:

$$\mathtt{matnew}[x\_]=\begin{pmatrix} 
x|_1 & 1 & 0& 0&0\\
1 & x^2|_1 & 0& 0&0\\
0& 0&x|_2 & 1 &0\\
0& 0&1 & x^2|_2 &0\\
0& 0&0 & 0&\ddots\\
\end{pmatrix}$$

where each block in this block-diagonal matrix is evaluated at a different consecutive number.
An interesting approach came up [here](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/59179/how-to-create-a-block-diagonal-matrix-by-repeating-a-submatrix-n-times). Particularly, the function

```
mats[p_, n_] := ArrayFlatten[DiagonalMatrix[Array[1 &, n]] /. {1 -> p, 0 -> 0 p}];
```

seems to be very helpful, but unfortunately each block will not be evaluated at different x. How should I change the function `Array[]` in this definition to get the above matrix `matnew[x_]` with `x = 1, x = 2`, ...?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
mat[x_] := {{x, 1}, {1, x^2}}

matnew[n_] := Block[{f}, 
  ArrayFlatten@(DiagonalMatrix[Array[f, n]] /. Table[f[i] -> mat[i], {i, n}])]

matnew[3]

(* {{1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0}, {1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0}, {0, 0, 2, 1, 0, 0}, 
   {0, 0, 1, 4, 0, 0}, {0, 0, 0, 0, 3, 1}, {0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 9}} *)

% // TeXForm
```

$
\left(
\begin{array}{cccccc}
 1 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
 1 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
 0 & 0 & 2 & 1 & 0 & 0 \\
 0 & 0 & 1 & 4 & 0 & 0 \\
 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 3 & 1 \\
 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 9 \\
\end{array}
\right)
$

Here is a more general version that allows fractional numbers

```
matnew2[imin_, imax_, di_] := 
 Block[{f}, 
  ArrayFlatten@(DiagonalMatrix[Table[f[i], {i, imin, imax, di}]] /. 
     Table[f[i] -> mat[i], {i, imin, imax, di}])]
```

`matnew2[1, 3, 1]` gives the same result as before:

$
\left(
\begin{array}{cccccc}
 1 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
 1 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
 0 & 0 & 2 & 1 & 0 & 0 \\
 0 & 0 & 1 & 4 & 0 & 0 \\
 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 3 & 1 \\
 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 9 \\
\end{array}
\right)
$

And, for example, with intervals of 1/2 instead of 1:

`matnew2[1, 3, 1/2]`

$
\left(
\begin{array}{cccccccccc}
 1 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
 1 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
 0 & 0 & \frac{3}{2} & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
 0 & 0 & 1 & \frac{9}{4} & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 2 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 4 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & \frac{5}{2} & 1 & 0 & 0 \\
 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 & \frac{25}{4} & 0 & 0 \\
 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 3 & 1 \\
 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 9 \\
\end{array}
\right)
$

Comment: This answer worked perfectly. How would I have to change it if I wanted fractions numbers instead of integers? More precisely, the Array[f, n] above should include a range like Array[f, n, {min,max}].

Comment: @xabdax I updated the function so it takes three values: min, max, and interval. Let me know if that's not what you meant.

Comment: This is exactly what I meant. Thanks!!

Answer (score 3):

```
mat = Array[x^(# Boole[# == #2]) &, {2, 2}];

n = 3;

mats = mat /. {x -> #} & /@ Range[n];

sa  = SparseArray[{Band[{1, 1}] -> mats}]

TeXForm @ MatrixForm @ sa
```

> $\left(
> \begin{array}{cccccc}
>  1 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
>  1 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
>  0 & 0 & 2 & 1 & 0 & 0 \\
>  0 & 0 & 1 & 4 & 0 & 0 \\
>  0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 3 & 1 \\
>  0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 9 \\
> \end{array}
> \right)$

Also

```
Control`BlockDiagonalMatrix @@ mats // MatrixForm // TeXForm
```

> same picture

```
Module[{i = 1}, ArrayFlatten[IdentityMatrix[n] /. {1 :> mats[[i++]]}]] // 
  MatrixForm // TeXForm
```

> same picture

Comment: How would this look like if [_] was an arbitrary function/matrix? I wrote x and x^2 to make the question look simpler but in reality my initial matrix is more complicated (and also bigger) than that.

Comment: will each block be evaluated at different integers? I updated the question to make this a little clearer. Basically I do not only need them to be on the diagonal but also each block should be evaluated at a different number.

Comment: @xabdax, please see the new version.

Comment: ``Control`BlockDiagonalMatrix @@ mats // MatrixForm // TeXForm ``  should be ``LinearAlgebra`BlockDiagonalMatrix[mats] // MatrixForm``  .

Answer (score 2):

Using an *undocumented* function:

```
With[{n = 3}, SparseArray`SparseBlockMatrix[Table[{x, x} -> {{x, 1}, {1, x^2}}, {x, 1, n}]]]
```

generates a block diagonal matrix as a `SparseArray[]`; use `Normal[]` if you wish to have an actual list instead.

---

In general, `` SparseArray`SparseBlockMatrix[] `` takes a list of rules corresponding to the positions of a specified block; e.g. `{1, 1} -> {{1, 1}, {1, 1}}` corresponds to block $(1,1)$ of the block matrix.

As another example, here is how to construct a block triangular matrix:

```
SparseArray`SparseBlockMatrix[{{1, 1} -> HilbertMatrix[2], {1, 2} -> IdentityMatrix[2],
                               {2, 2} -> Array[Min, {2, 2}]}] // Normal
   {{1, 1/2, 1, 0}, {1/2, 1/3, 0, 1}, {0, 0, 1, 1}, {0, 0, 1, 2}}
```