# How to insert a Matrix into a larger matrix

Tags: list-manipulation, matrix

I have a 4x4 matrix

```
      v1 v2 v3 v4

myM={{a1,a2,c1,c2},    v1
     {a2,a3,c2,c3},    v2
     {c1,c2,d1,d2},    v3
     {c2,c3,d2,d3}}    v4
```

And I want to insert this matrix into a 8x8 matrix as follows:

```
       u1  u2  v1  v2  u3  u4  v3  v4

myLM={{ 0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0},    u1
      { 0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0},    u2
      { 0,  0, a1, a2,  0,  0, c1, c2},    v1
      { 0,  0, a2, a3,  0,  0, c2, c3},    v2
      { 0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0},    u3
      { 0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0},    u4
      { 0,  0, c1, c2,  0,  0, d1, d2},    v3
      { 0,  0, c2, c3,  0,  0, d2, d3}}    v4
```

Is there a way to do this without index-nightmares?

It would also be great if the answer was general enough, in a sense that it works for 2x2 or also 8x8 matrices that I want to include into a larger matrix.

Both the smaller and the larger matrix have always an even number of columns/rows. And I divide the small and large matrices in 4 blocks and place each sub-block of the small matrix into the corresponding one of the large matrix. So in the given example the index 3 would be given and then it is clear how to insert the matrix (a1-> (3,3) and the rest follows).

So the general idea is I guess, that one has a matrix in some basis representation and wants to have this matrix now in a larger vector space adding the appropriate zeros and matrix elements etc.)

Initial basis:

```
{v1,v2,...,v1',v2'...}
```

New Basis (inserting at position n):

```
{u1,u2,...,un-1,v1,v2,...,un,....,u1',u2',...,un-1',v1',v2',...,un',...}
```

Comment: where did the b's come from? b1,b2,....? did you mean d1,d2,....?

Comment: yes indeed, my bad

Comment: Your `myM` has many repeated identical elements. Is that always the case, or are they supposed to be all different? I mean, is there a pattern we can assume for the repetitions? Also, do you only need zeros in the large matrix to start with? This would affect the degree to which one could simplify things.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I propose:

```
quarter = Partition[#, Dimensions[#]/2] &;

pad = PadLeft[#, Dimensions@#2, #2] &;

matrixInsert[small_, large_] :=
  ArrayFlatten[ pad @@ quarter /@ {small, large} ]
```

Test:

```
myM = {{a1, a2, c1, c2}, {a2, a3, c2, c3}, {c1, c2, d1, d2}, {c2, c3, d2, d3}};

myLM = Array[Plus, {8, 8}, {0, 1}];

matrixInsert[myM, myLM] // MatrixForm
```

> $\left(
> \begin{array}{cccccccc}
>  1 & 2 & 3 & 4 & 5 & 6 & 7 & 8 \\
>  2 & 3 & 4 & 5 & 6 & 7 & 8 & 9 \\
>  3 & 4 & \text{a1} & \text{a2} & 7 & 8 & \text{c1} & \text{c2} \\
>  4 & 5 & \text{a2} & \text{a3} & 8 & 9 & \text{c2} & \text{c3} \\
>  5 & 6 & 7 & 8 & 9 & 10 & 11 & 12 \\
>  6 & 7 & 8 & 9 & 10 & 11 & 12 & 13 \\
>  7 & 8 & \text{c1} & \text{c2} & 11 & 12 & \text{d1} & \text{d2} \\
>  8 & 9 & \text{c2} & \text{c3} & 12 & 13 & \text{d2} & \text{d3} \\
> \end{array}
> \right)$

---

Here is an extension to control placement of the smaller blocks within the larger blocks.

```
ClearAll[quarter, pad, matrixInsert]

quarter = Partition[#, Dimensions[#]/2] &;

pad[pos_][a_, b_] := PadRight[a, Dimensions@b, b ~RotateLeft~ pos, pos];

matrixInsert[small_, large_, r_: 0, c_: 0] := 
  pad[{0, 0, r, c}] @@ quarter /@ {small, large} // ArrayFlatten
```

Test:

```
matrixInsert[myM, myLM] // MatrixForm   (* default *)
```

> $\left(
> \begin{array}{cccccccc}
>  \text{a1} & \text{a2} & 3 & 4 & \text{c1} & \text{c2} & 7 & 8 \\
>  \text{a2} & \text{a3} & 6 & 7 & \text{c2} & \text{c3} & 10 & 11 \\
>  7 & 8 & 9 & 10 & 11 & 12 & 13 & 14 \\
>  10 & 11 & 12 & 13 & 14 & 15 & 16 & 17 \\
>  \text{c1} & \text{c2} & 15 & 16 & \text{d1} & \text{d2} & 19 & 20 \\
>  \text{c2} & \text{c3} & 18 & 19 & \text{d2} & \text{d3} & 22 & 23 \\
>  19 & 20 & 21 & 22 & 23 & 24 & 25 & 26 \\
>  22 & 23 & 24 & 25 & 26 & 27 & 28 & 29 \\
> \end{array}
> \right)$

```
matrixInsert[myM, myLM, 1] // MatrixForm  (* one row down *)
```

> $\left(
> \begin{array}{cccccccc}
>  1 & 2 & 3 & 4 & 5 & 6 & 7 & 8 \\
>  \text{a1} & \text{a2} & 6 & 7 & \text{c1} & \text{c2} & 10 & 11 \\
>  \text{a2} & \text{a3} & 9 & 10 & \text{c2} & \text{c3} & 13 & 14 \\
>  10 & 11 & 12 & 13 & 14 & 15 & 16 & 17 \\
>  13 & 14 & 15 & 16 & 17 & 18 & 19 & 20 \\
>  \text{c1} & \text{c2} & 18 & 19 & \text{d1} & \text{d2} & 22 & 23 \\
>  \text{c2} & \text{c3} & 21 & 22 & \text{d2} & \text{d3} & 25 & 26 \\
>  22 & 23 & 24 & 25 & 26 & 27 & 28 & 29 \\
> \end{array}
> \right)$

```
matrixInsert[myM, myLM, 1, 2] // MatrixForm  (* one row down, two columns in *)
```

> $\left(
> \begin{array}{cccccccc}
>  1 & 2 & 3 & 4 & 5 & 6 & 7 & 8 \\
>  4 & 5 & \text{a1} & \text{a2} & 8 & 9 & \text{c1} & \text{c2} \\
>  7 & 8 & \text{a2} & \text{a3} & 11 & 12 & \text{c2} & \text{c3} \\
>  10 & 11 & 12 & 13 & 14 & 15 & 16 & 17 \\
>  13 & 14 & 15 & 16 & 17 & 18 & 19 & 20 \\
>  16 & 17 & \text{c1} & \text{c2} & 20 & 21 & \text{d1} & \text{d2} \\
>  19 & 20 & \text{c2} & \text{c3} & 23 & 24 & \text{d2} & \text{d3} \\
>  22 & 23 & 24 & 25 & 26 & 27 & 28 & 29 \\
> \end{array}
> \right)$

Comment: That looks neat. What is the `, 2` for in `matrixInsert` ? I just removed it and got the same result (Mathematica 10)
And is there any way I can control the position of the small matrix within the quarter part of the large one?

Comment: @MrZ If you want to have a more general approach, then you may want to look at [@kguler's answer here](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/49315/245). But then your question should have made it clearer that you want a more general outcome.

Comment: @Jens I thought that Mr.Wizard's code is already able to do what I asked for and that I was just unable to see how to change it accordingly. I do not understand why his code places the smaller matrix in the lower right corner.

Comment: @MrZ The positioning is in the `PadLeft` command. You could use `ArrayPad` there, too. That would allow arbitrary positioning.

Comment: @MrZ (1) I hadn't thought about it but yes I guess in this case the result is the same even without the level parameter of `MapThread`.  In fact `MapThread` can be eliminated.  You can control placement by using the forth parameter of `PadLeft`, e.g. `PadLeft[#, Dimensions@#2, #2, 1]`, or by using `PadRight` instead.   `ArrayPad` could also be used but its padding specification is additive rather than absolute.

Comment: Your suggestion with PadLeft[...,1] doesn't work for me. I get `{{11, 12, 13, 10, 7, 8, 9, 6}, {12, d1, d2, 11, 8, 9, 10, 7}, {13, d2,
   d3, 12, 9, 10, 11, 8}, {10, 11, 12, 9, 6, 7, 8, 5}, {7, 8, 9, 6, 3,
   4, 5, 2}, {8, 9, 10, 7, 4, 5, 6, 3}, {9, 10, 11, 8, 5, 6, 7, 
  4}, {6, 7, 8, 5, 2, 3, 4, 1}}`

Comment: @MrZ You're right again.  Sorry for the crummy suggestion.  I'm sort of distracted these days I guess.  For the current code I would need `PadLeft[#, Dimensions@#2, #2, {0, 0, 1, 1}]` for what I originally meant, but it *still* doesn't work right and never did.  Let me think about this and get back to you.  `PadRight` *does* work for upper-left insertion at least.

Comment: @MrZ Please see the updated answer.

Answer (score 4):

If the larger matrix consists of zeros (or other *equal* elements), one can use `SparseArray` function:

```
myM = {{a1, a2, c1, c2}, {a2, a3, c2, c3}, {c1, c2, d1, d2}, {c2, c3, 
d2, d3}};
newM = SparseArray[{Band[{3, 3}] -> myM[[1 ;; 2, 1 ;; 2]],
   Band[{3, 7}] -> myM[[1 ;; 2, 3 ;; 4]],
   Band[{7, 3}] -> myM[[3 ;; 4, 1 ;; 2]],
   Band[{7, 7}] -> myM[[3 ;; 4, 3 ;; 4]]}, {8, 8}]
```

Here `Band[{3, 3}]->A` says that starting from position {3,3} matrix A should be inserted. And `myM[[i ;; j, k ;; m]]` is just a submatrix of your small matrix. More information on `Band` can be found in documentation.

To get sparse matrix in normal form type:

```
newM // Normal
```

Answer (score 4):

```
myM2 = Nest[Insert[#, 0, {{1}, {1}, {3}, {3}}] & /@ Transpose[#] &,  myM, 2];
myM2 // MatrixForm // TeXForm
```

> $\left(
> \begin{array}{cccccccc}
>  0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
>  0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
>  0 & 0 & \text{a1} & \text{a2} & 0 & 0 & \text{c1} & \text{c2} \\
>  0 & 0 & \text{a2} & \text{a3} & 0 & 0 & \text{c2} & \text{c3} \\
>  0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
>  0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
>  0 & 0 & \text{c1} & \text{c2} & 0 & 0 & \text{d1} & \text{d2} \\
>  0 & 0 & \text{c2} & \text{c3} & 0 & 0 & \text{d2} & \text{d3} \\
> \end{array}
> \right)$