# How to form a diagonal matrix from sub-matrices?

Tags: matrix

I have a 3x3 matrix (let's say G) and a 3x3 matrix of zeros (let's say zero). I want a diagonal matrix in the form Diag[G; G; G; zero] such that the size of matrix becomes 12x12. I actually have to add this diagonal matrix to another 12x12 matrix.

I have already tried the solutions of [How to form a block-diagonal matrix from a list of matrices?](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/19778/how-to-form-a-block-diagonal-matrix-from-a-list-of-matrices) and [Create a matrix of matrices using Band and ArrayFlatten](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/49311/create-a-matrix-of-matrices-using-band-and-arrayflatten/49315#49315) but they don't give me a correct result when I check the dimensions of the diagonal matrix. Is there a method that I can use to achieve this result?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

```
g = ArrayReshape[Range[9], {3, 3}];
m = KroneckerProduct[DiagonalMatrix[{1, 1, 1, 0}], g]
m // MatrixForm
```

$$
\left(
\begin{array}{cccccccccccc}
 1 & 2 & 3 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
 4 & 5 & 6 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
 7 & 8 & 9 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 2 & 3 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
 0 & 0 & 0 & 4 & 5 & 6 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
 0 & 0 & 0 & 7 & 8 & 9 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 2 & 3 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 4 & 5 & 6 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 7 & 8 & 9 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
\end{array}
\right)
$$

Comment: Thank you, this works very cleanly and easily.

Comment: @YogeshPilania the nice thing about the Kronecker product is you can place a sub-matrix everywhere a 1 appears in its argument matrix with all other entries zero, so it's easy to extend to other patterns.

Answer (score 8):

How about

```
G = Array[a, {3, 3}];
Format[a[i_, j_]] = Subscript[a, i, j];
B = ArrayFlatten[{{G,0,0,0},{0,G,0,0}, {0,0,G,0},{0,0,0*G}} ]
```

[image]

Comment: This is 9x9. OP wanted 12x12 - I think you need to change it to `{{G,0,0,0},{0,G,0,0}, {0,0,G,0},{0,0,0,0}}`

Comment: Thanks @chris for the solution.

Answer (score 7):

As suggested in [this post](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/99577) (and a couple of others), there is the undocumented function `` SparseArray`SparseBlockMatrix `` that allows you to do that quite efficiently.

```
g = ArrayReshape[Range[9], {3, 3}];
rules = {{1, 1} -> g, {2, 2} -> g, {3, 3} -> g, {4, 4} -> 0 g};
A = SparseArray`SparseBlockMatrix[rules];
```

This function allows the argument pattern `` SparseArray`SparseBlockMatrix[rules,dims,background] ``, where `dims` stands probably for the total matrix dimension. But apparently, there is a bug and `` SparseArray`SparseBlockMatrix `` just ignores any given second argument. So make sure that the first and last diagonal block are always present.

Answer (score 6):

I am always fond of the outer product in situations like this...

```
g = Partition[Range[9], 3];
m = ArrayFlatten@Outer[Times, DiagonalMatrix[{1, 1, 1, 0}], g]
m // MatrixForm
```

Answer (score 5):

```
G = {{a, b, c}, {d, e, f}, {g, h, i}};
s = Normal[SparseArray[Band[{1, 1}] -> {G, G, G}, {12, 12}]] // MatrixForm
```

$$
\left(
\begin{array}{cccccccccccc}
 a & b & c & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
 d & e & f & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
 g & h & i & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
 0 & 0 & 0 & a & b & c & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
 0 & 0 & 0 & d & e & f & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
 0 & 0 & 0 & g & h & i & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & a & b & c & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & d & e & f & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & g & h & i & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
\end{array}
\right)
$$