# How to extract the list of all matrices from a Block Diagonal Matrix?

Tags: list-manipulation, matrix

I am working on a function to do the opposite operation of [How to form a block-diagonal Matrix from a list of matrices?](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/19778/how-to-form-a-block-diagonal-matrix-from-a-list-of-matrices)

Here is my current algorithm: For `i` starting at 1, scan the elements of index `(i,1...i-1)` and `(1...i-1,i)`, if they are all zero, take the top left $(i-1)(i-1)$ matrix out and return the rest matrix from `(i,i)` as `(1,1)`.

```
extractBDM[mat_?MatrixQ] := 
 Flatten[Last@Reap@NestWhile[
 Module[{pos}, 
   pos = FirstPosition[
     Table[Plus @@ (#[[i + 1, ;; i]] ~
          Join~#[[;; i, i + 1]])^2, {i, 1, Length@# - 1}], 0]; 
   If[MissingQ[pos], Sow[#]; {}, pos = pos[[1]]; 
    Sow[#[[;; pos, ;; pos]]]; #[[pos + 1 ;;, pos + 1 ;;]]]] &, 
 mat, # != {} &], 1]
```

However this algorithm does not support the existence of non-square matrices on the diagonal, and the `Table` inside is calculating the whole matrix, while this is unnecessary. Are there better ways to solve this problem?

On uniqueness: In the result matrices, for every diagonal element, say it is index is `{i,i}`, there should be at least one non-zero element among `{1,i}, {2,i}, ...,{i-1,i} and {i,1}, {i,2}, ...,{i,i-1}`; also the diagonal elements are all non-zero.

Comment: Just a toy example which is assuming there are no `0` in blocks: `SplitBy[m, Unitize] /. (0 -> Nothing) // Map@MatrixForm`

Comment: +1 for an interesting question, but you realize that allowing zeros in the blocks, noted by Kuba, means some reversals are not unique. How would you propose those are to be handled?

Comment: @ciao I added some clarifications, is there any ambiguity now?

Comment: How would you want $$\begin{pmatrix}
 0 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
 0 & 0 & 1 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 \\
 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 0 \\
 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 0 \\
 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 \\
\end{pmatrix}$$ to be handled?

Comment: @J.M. I have added that the diagonal elements are non-zero. But This problem is not a fake one, it is from a real math problem. The matrix is a result from Jordan Decomposition, and even if there are sometimes zeros in a block, the 1 is likely to stick with other non-zero numbers. I know you are an expert in mathematics, I would appreciate it if you can help me describe this question clearly.

Comment: "This problem is not a fake one" - I don't doubt that this is a real problem of yours, but since you mention the Jordan form, you should know that although Jordan blocks are *always* square, one can certainly have a Jordan block corresponding to zero, in different blocks, like $$\begin{pmatrix}
 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
 0 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 0 \\
 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 0 \\
\end{pmatrix}$$ (i.e. a *derogatory* matrix).

Comment: In a sense, however, breaking up the Jordan form is easier, as you only have to scan either the sub- or superdiagonal (depending on your chosen convention) on where you should break.

Comment: @J.M. Sorry I did not take that into account...  I am trying to sort the Jordan blocks in a decomposition( mathematics won't do it), and my primary idea was to first extract the blocks, sort them, and reconstruct. I didn't expect the case to be so complicated.

Comment: In any event: [this article](http://dx.doi.org/10.1137/1002025) might be of interest to you. FWIW: anybody who is trying to re-implement `MatrixFunction[]` will bump into this precise problem, to give an example application.

Answer (score 9):

```
extractBDM[mat_?MatrixQ] := 
 Pick[mat, #, 1] & /@ 
   Values[ComponentMeasurements[
     Image[MorphologicalTransform[Unitize[mat], "BoundingBoxes"]], 
     "Mask", CornerNeighbors -> False]] /. {} -> Nothing
```

## Explanation

I just treat the values as an image pixel.So our purpose is finding the connected component.Supose your list `mat` is

```
MatrixForm[
 mat = {{10, 2, 0, 0, 0}, {0, 5, 0, 0, 0}, {0, 0, 7, 3, 0}, {0, 0, 0, 
    4, 0}, {0, 0, 0, 0, 6}}]
```

$\left(
\begin{array}{ccccc}
 10 & 2 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
 0 & 5 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
 0 & 0 & 7 & 3 & 0 \\
 0 & 0 & 0 & 4 & 0 \\
 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 6 \\
\end{array}
\right)$

Well these pixel of bounding boxes is what we want

```
Image[MorphologicalTransform[Unitize[mat], "BoundingBoxes"]]
```

[image]

Then we use `Pick` to select every component's pixel in `mat`

## Usage

```
MatrixForm[mat]
```

$\left(
\begin{array}{ccccc}
 10 & 2 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
 0 & 5 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
 0 & 0 & 7 & 3 & 0 \\
 0 & 0 & 0 & 4 & 0 \\
 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 6 \\
\end{array}
\right)$

```
extractBDM[mat]
```

> {{{10,2},{0,5}},{{7,3},{0,4}},{{6}}}

Or the [matrix `m` from Sumit](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/120435/21532)

```
MatrixForm[
 m = {{5, 3, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0}, {4, 2, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0}, {0, 0, 0, 9,
     9, 2, 0, 0}, {0, 0, 4, 2, 3, 6, 0, 0}, {0, 0, 3, 7, 5, 1, 0, 
    0}, {0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 3, 1}, {0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 7}}]
```

$\left(
\begin{array}{cccccccc}
 5 & 3 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
 4 & 2 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
 0 & 0 & 0 & 9 & 9 & 2 & 0 & 0 \\
 0 & 0 & 4 & 2 & 3 & 6 & 0 & 0 \\
 0 & 0 & 3 & 7 & 5 & 1 & 0 & 0 \\
 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 3 & 1 \\
 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 7 \\
\end{array}
\right)$

```
MatrixForm /@ extractBDM[m]
```

[image]

Comment: +1 I just knew there had to be a graphical solution

Comment: @LLlAMnYP Thanks.Just strike to my mind. :)

Comment: "+1", but this method doesn't work if the matrix is huge and the blocks are a bit sparse.

Answer (score 3):

I am not sure if this is what you want (it would be helpful if you can give an example in your question). What I am doing here is to get the block matrix at any given position.

First I create a general matrix.

```
a = RandomInteger[{1, 9}, {2, 2}];
b = RandomInteger[{1, 9}, {3, 4}];
c = RandomInteger[{1, 9}, {2, 2}];
m = SparseArray[{Band[{1, 1}] -> a, Band[{3, 3}] -> b, Band[{6, 7}] -> c}] // Normal;
m = ReplacePart[m, {3, 3} -> 0];
MatrixForm[m]
```

> $\begin{pmatrix}
>  5 & 3 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
>  4 & 2 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
>  0 & 0 & 0 & 9 & 9 & 2 & 0 & 0 \\
>  0 & 0 & 4 & 2 & 3 & 6 & 0 & 0 \\
>  0 & 0 & 3 & 7 & 5 & 1 & 0 & 0 \\
>  0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 3 & 1 \\
>  0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 7 \\
> \end{pmatrix}$

Now I want to get the block at `{3,3}`

```
{n1, n2} = {3, 3};

r1 = Flatten[SparseArray[m[[n1, All]]]["NonzeroPositions"]];
c1 = Flatten[SparseArray[m[[All, n2]]]["NonzeroPositions"]];
r2 = Flatten[SparseArray[m[[#, All]]]["NonzeroPositions"] & /@ c1];
c2 = Flatten[SparseArray[m[[All, #]]]["NonzeroPositions"] & /@ r1];
{b21, b22} = {Min[#], Max[#]} &@c2;
{b11, b12} = {Min[#], Max[#]} &@r2;
m1 = m[[b21 ;; b22, b11 ;; b12]];

MatrixForm[m1]
```

> $\begin{pmatrix}
>  0 & 9 & 9 & 2 \\
>  4 & 2 & 3 & 6 \\
>  3 & 7 & 5 & 1 \\
> \end{pmatrix}$

For the first block take `{n1, n2} = {1, 1}`.

Comment: Thanks, but your function does not work properly when the last elements of the first row/column are zero, eg. the first row is 9,9,0.

Comment: @happyfish, now it will work. I modified it for any diagonal block.

Answer (score 2):

I'll give two solutions here:

1. a not-that elegant solution which can apply to multiple sizes but all blocks **MUST** be Fully filled! (Just the limitations of Morphological methods)

   ```
   Function[{n}, Pick[mat, #, n] /. {} -> Nothing] /@ Range@Max@# &@
    MorphologicalComponents[mat, Method -> "BoundingBox", 
     CornerNeighbors -> False]
   ```

This use mainly the `MorphologicalComponents` function and find out the blocks in a Morphological way.

2. If, as I suppose, you're dealing with Jordan Blocks :) Then this will work.

   ```
   mat[[#, #]] & /@ Thread[Prepend[#, 1] ;; Append[#, Length@mat]] &@
   Flatten@Position[Diagonal[mat, 1], 0]
   ```

This use the property of Jordan blocks. Check [MathWorld](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/JordanBlock.html) and find it out~

Hope this can help you~

---

## UPDATE for Solution 1

The limitation of `MorphologicalComponents` can be overcome with some easy manipulation. Changing it to this function and it will always do a great job~

```
newMorphologicalComponents[mat_] := 
 NestWhile[
  MorphologicalComponents[#, CornerNeighbors -> False, 
    Method -> "BoundingBox"] &, mat, UnsameQ, 2]
```

As you can see, this will do multiple times of Morphological components till all overlapping components merge into one huge cluster which is just what we need.

Comment: the first code is, in some aspects, a simplified and more direct solution of @yode 's solution.

Comment: Poor composing but actually have better efficiency than me. :)

Comment: "than my solution" or "than mine"~ :P

Comment: Aha..Thanks for pointing that.

Comment: Updated, this time `MorphologicalComponents`' drawback has been overcame~@yode

Answer (score 0):

You can treat your input matrix as the adjacency matrix of a graph, and then each block corresponds to a different connected component in the graph. You can conveniently extract these using the function ConnectedComponents[], so a one line answer to your question is then

```
Table[m[[comp, comp]], {comp, ConnectedComponents@AdjacencyGraph@Unitize@m}]
```

or, more succinctly,

```
m[[#, #]] & /@ ConnectedComponents@AdjacencyGraph@Unitize@m
```

Comment: Note there are [some thing](http://i.stack.imgur.com/MmwiH.png) should be tunning still.

Comment: It is unclear to me how to define a (unique and reasonable) decomposition when blocks are non-square. For example, the matrix

{
 {1, 1, 1, 0, 0},
 {1, 1, 1, 0, 0},
 {0, 0, 1, 1, 1},
 {0, 0, 0, 1, 1},
 {0, 0, 0, 1, 1}
}

may be decomposed in a number of different ways, in two or three blocks, etc

Comment: Another thing to be aware of is the case where connected components are between nods which aren't "close" to each other. For example, if you only have connections form node 5 to 8, and only between 6 and 7, then this algorithm will output a block for 5 and 8 and another one for 6,7. To fix it just take the connected components and add the missing numbers, {5,8} --> {5,6,7,8}. Or reorder the basis and avoid all this. Depends on how flexible the problem is.