# generate a block matrix

Tags: list-manipulation, matrix

We have two numbers: `a` and `b`, and $N$ submatrices (here $N=3$ but it should be generalized): `m1`, `m2`, `m3`. The dimension of two sub matrices `m1` and `m3` are similar and lower than the dimension of `m2`. For example: `m1` and `m3` are $r\times r$, but `m2` is $s\times s$ and $r<s$.

We wish to construct a bigger matrix whose dimension is `d` that is equal to $2r+s+2$. (2 for two numbers) in a such way that the numbers and submatrices be on the diagonal of the bigger matrix (as some blocks on the diagonal same as the below schematic picture).

```
m1 = m3 = {{1, 0, 0, 0}, {0, 1, 0, -1}, {1, 0, -1, 0}, {1, 1, -1, -1}};
m2 = {{-1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0}, 
      {1, -1, -1, -1, 1, -1}, 
      {-1, 0, 1, 0, -1, 1}, 
      {-1, -1, 1, 1, 1, 0}, 
      {0, -1, 0, 0, -1, -1}, 
      {0, 0, 1, -1, -1, 1}}
```

The two numbers are $2$ and $-2$. The desired matrix is $16\times16$.

Comment: Inzo, out of curiosity, why did you revert my clean-up edits? Had I mistakenly mis-represented your question?

Comment: So sorry, I did not revert intentionally your editing. I was adding somethings in the question and I could not understand what I should did correctly. Please take your editing my question to be pretended better

Comment: So sorry for that. I pressed a key incorrectly. It caused your editing was not applied

Comment: possible duplicate q/a: [How to form a block-diagonal matrix from a list of matrices?](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/19778/125)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Using an *undocumented* function:

```
SparseArray`SparseBlockMatrix[{{1, 1} -> {{2}}, {2, 2} -> m1, {3, 3} -> m2,
                               {4, 4} -> m3, {5, 5} -> {{-2}}}]
```

$$\begin{pmatrix}
 2 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
 0 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
 0 & 0 & 1 & 0 & -1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
 0 & 1 & 0 & -1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
 0 & 1 & 1 & -1 & -1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & -1 & 1 & 1 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 & -1 & -1 & -1 & 1 & -1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & -1 & 0 & 1 & 0 & -1 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & -1 & -1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & -1 & 0 & 0 & -1 & -1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 & -1 & -1 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 0 & -1 & 0 \\
 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 0 & -1 & 0 & 0 \\
 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 1 & -1 & -1 & 0 \\
 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & -2 \\
\end{pmatrix}$$

Answer (score 9):

Here is a version that is concise, flexible, and free of undocumented functions:

```
SparseArray[
  Band[{1, 1}] -> {m1, {{2}}, {{-2}}, m2, m3}
] // MatrixForm
```

[image]

If you want to add more blocks or numbers, just add them to the list, numbers wrapped in `{{n}}`, as shown above.

Comment: If you're going to put two scalars next to each other on a diagonal band, you might as well do `Band[{1, 1}] -> {m1, DiagonalMatrix[{2, -2}], m2, m3}`

Comment: @J.M.: True, but this way it is clear that the scalars can be put anywhere in the sequence.

Answer (score 5):

If I understand what  you are looking for, the most expeditious way might be to use `SparseArray` and treat each sub matrix as a `Band`; you can recover a regular array using `Normal`. Consider:

```
MatrixForm@
 SparseArray[{
    {1, 1} -> 2, {-1, -1} -> -2,
    Band[{2, 2}] -> m1, Band[{2, 2} + Dimensions[m1]] -> m2, 
    Band[{2, 2} + Dimensions[m1] + Dimensions[m2]] -> m3
   }, {16, 16}
 ]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]