# Set of quadratic forms and linear algebra

Tags: matrix, linear-algebra, tensors, vector-calculus

I have a set of quadratic forms.

$L_{1}=u_1^TJ_{1}u_1$

$L_{2}=u_2^TJ_{2}u_2$

$L_{3}=u_3^TJ_{3}u_3$

where $u_{i=1,2,3}$ - 3$\times$1 vector;

where $J_{i=1,2,3}$ - 3$\times$3 matrix;

I need to pack their into a single operation in such a way that I get a matrix of the following form:

$\boldsymbol{L}=\begin{bmatrix}L_1 & 0 & 0\\0 & L_2 & 0\\0 & 0 & L_3\end{bmatrix}$

I'm assuming this can be done using a tensor operation as well as combining vectors into a matrix. Probably, something like that:

$\boldsymbol{L} \approx ? \boldsymbol{u}^T\boldsymbol{J}\boldsymbol{u}$ or $\boldsymbol{L} \approx \boldsymbol{u}^T \otimes ? \boldsymbol{J} \otimes ? \boldsymbol{u}$

But the problem turned out to be that, firstly, my $J$-matrices are different, and secondly, there are side off-diagonal elements in the result.So far, I haven't come up with a suitable operation.

```
TensorProduct[{Subscript[u, 1], Subscript[u, 2], Subscript[u, 3]}, 
 TensorProduct[{Subscript[u, 1], Subscript[u, 2], Subscript[u, 
   3]}, {J}]]
```

I need help and advice. Thank you for attention!

Comment: My deleted answer did not answer the question.  You are asking for a 3x3 matrix with the quadratic forms on the the diagonal.  My "answer" had $J_1$, $J_2$, $J_3$ on the diagonal, not the $L_i$'s.  Sorry for the confusion.

Comment: @LouisB never mind :) we'll think of something

Comment: Might this help? https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/153181/35390 Constructing block-diagonal matrices this way also works for non-square matrices.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am not sure if I understand the question correctly, but if what you want is to produce a block diagonal matrix from a list of `u`'s and a list of `J`'s then

```
us = {u1, u2, u3};
Js = {J1, J2, J3};
DD = DiagonalMatrix[Inner[Dot, us, Inner[Dot, Js, us, List], List]]
```

will produce

> {{u1 . J1 . u1, 0, 0}, {0, u2 . J2 . u2, 0}, {0, 0, u3 . J3 . u3}}

as you want. It also works if the `u`'s are Arrays of length `n` and the `J`'s are `n`x`n` matrices. If you prefer to work with `n`x`1` matrices then you will need to transpose the `us` in the outer `Inner`.

If you already have the `L`'s then `DiagonalMatrix` is all you need.

Comment: In general, yes, you correctly caught my question. And I understand that, apparently, it is clearly possible to come up with more than one such ways. I will consider your option, just write, please, the formula by which this problem is solved.

Comment: That would be `DiagonalMatrix[Inner[Dot, us, Inner[Dot, Js, us, List], List]]`. Or do you still have something that needs to be addressed?

Comment: Yes, please, write your line in the form of a mathematical formula.

Comment: This line is the formula: it is applying an inner product in which multiplication is `Dot` and sum is `List` twice, followed by the structural operation `DiagonalMatrix` that takes a list into a diagonal matrix.

Answer (score 1):

First define the ui and ji using helper functions:

```
u[i_] := {Subscript[u, i, 1], Subscript[u, i, 2], Subscript[u, i, 3]}
{u1, u2, u3} = u /@ {1, 2, 3};
j[i_] := Table[Subscript[j, i, i1, i2], {i1, 3}, {i2, 3}];
{j1, j2, j3} = j /@ {1, 2, 3};
```

Now it is easy to create the final matrix:

```
mat={{u1 . j1 . u1, 0, 0}, {0, u2 . j2 . u2, 0}, {0, 0, u3 . j3 . u3}};
mat // MatrixForm
```

[image]

Addendum

If you want to create the matrix automatically instead by hand, you may write:

```
DiagonalMatrix[
 MapThread[#1 . #2 . #1 &, {{u1, u2, u3}, {j1, j2, j3}}]]
```

Comment: Daniel, yes, this method works. But the matrix is constructed forcibly, i.e. has the desired structure forcibly. I would like to get the same matrix, but using tensors, or possibly outer and inner products, probably... As suggested in another answer in this thread.

Comment: I added the code to create the diagonal matrix by code.