# Speeding up generation of block diagonal matrix

Tags: matrix, performance-tuning, sparse-arrays

I'm struggling with the following problem. I have $48$ square matrices (full, filled with real machine precision numbers, thus are packed, all different) of size $128$. I wolud like to place them on a diagonal of sparse array of dimension $48\times 128=6144$. The method<sup>[(1)](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/19779/121)</sup>

```
SparseArray @ ArrayFlatten @ ReleaseHold @ DiagonalMatrix[Hold /@ matrices]
(* matrices is a list of 48 matices 128 x 128,
   e.g. matrices = RandomReal[{}, {128, 128}] & /@ Range[48] *)
```

is too slow (it takes ~6s on my laptop). I'm suspecting that the problem is with the `ArrayFlatten` function, since this produces huge matrix $6144\times 6144$ filled moslty with zeros (in some sense it unpacks sparse array). Is there any way to do the same but much faster (more efficient)? In a fraction of a second (I'm optimistic)? I've looked at `` "SparseArray`" `` context but without much success (`` SparseArray`VectorToDiagonalSparseArray `` seems to be equivalent to `DiagonalMatrix` so accepts only vectiors/lists). (Specific numbers given here are just for tests, in the end I would like to increase size of my problem, but then it of course gets even worse.)

After posting this question I've found the code on [MathWorld](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/BlockDiagonalMatrix.html) which gives me the result in ~3.63s. Code by ybeltukov `SparseArray[Band@{1, 1} -> matrices]` is even faster (~2.48s) but still far from being *ideal*.

Update: I've checked that asymptotically execution time scales as (based on `AbsoluteTiming`):

- $m^{2}n^{2}$ for `BlockDiagonalMatrix`
- $m^{2}n^{1}$ for recent version of `blockArray` by ybeltukov

where: $n$ is a number of matrices/blocks and $m$ is a size of a single matix/block.

Comment: The idiomatic `SparseArray[Band@{1, 1} -> matrices]` is 2 times faster. However, I think it can be improved further.

Comment: Related, but not a duplicate: [How to form a block-diagonal Matrix from a list of matrices?](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/19778/4678)

Comment: @ybeltukov Thank you, I'm looking for something way faster. This question (19778) is where I've found presented (reference) solution.

Comment: Also related: [Efficient method to generate Tridiagonal 50 by 50 Matrix?](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/59704/4678)

Answer (score 31, accepted):

You are right, it can be done in a fraction of second. One can explicitly construct an array of indexes

```
blockArray[mat_] := SparseArray[
  Tuples[Range@# - {1, 0, 0}].{Rest@#, {1, 0}, {0, 1}} &@Dimensions@mat -> 
   Flatten@mat]
```

Timings:

```
matrices = RandomReal[1, {48, 128, 128}];

s1 = 
   SparseArray@
    ArrayFlatten@ReleaseHold@DiagonalMatrix[Hold /@ matrices]; // RepeatedTiming
(* {7.56, Null} *)

s2 = SparseArray[Band@{1, 1} -> matrices]; // RepeatedTiming
(* {4.03, Null} *)

s3 = blockArray[matrices]; // RepeatedTiming
(* {0.097, Null} *)

TrueQ[s1 == s2 == s3]
(* True *)
```

For further acceleration you can create the [internal structure](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/18081/4678) of the `SparseArray` directly

```
c = Compile[{{b, _Integer}, {h, _Integer}, {w, _Integer}},
   Partition[Flatten@Table[k + i w, {i, 0, b - 1}, {j, h}, {k, w}], 1], 
   CompilationTarget -> "C", RuntimeOptions -> "Speed"];

blockArray2[mat_] := 
 SparseArray @@ {Automatic, # {##2}, 
     0, {1, {Range[0, 1 ##, #3], c@##}, Flatten@mat}} & @@ Dimensions@mat

s4 = blockArray2[matrices]; // RepeatedTiming
(* {0.031, Null} *)

s3 == s4
(* True *)
```

Comment: Many thanks! This is great. I was going to ask whetere it can be further improved, but since you are still improving timings...

Comment: @mmal Yes, I know one more hack :)

Comment: I would be grateful.

Comment: @mmal Please check the update. Note, that you can further accelerate `SparseArray` construction with `LibraryLink` and high-efficient C code.

Comment: Compiled generation of sparse array structure is very promising. Unfortunately I'm not aware of `LibraryLink` technology. I'm still wondering whether any undocumented function from ``SparseArray`` could do the trick.

Comment: I stumbled onto this today while looking for some information on `SparseArray`.  I'd never have guessed that this would be so much faster! Thank you.

Answer (score 13):

There is an undocumented built-in solution:

```
rules = {#, #} -> RandomReal[{}, {128, 128}] & /@ Range[48];
SparseArray`SparseBlockMatrix[rules]; // RepeatedTiming

(* {0.042, Null} *)
```

Answer (score 2):

Version 13.1 introduced [`BlockDiagonalMatrix`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/BlockDiagonalMatrix.html) (labeled as Experimental).

On my computer, it performs similarly to ybeltukov's `blockArray` (using the setup from the [answer](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/99468/5115)):

```
s3 = blockArray[matrices]; // RepeatedTiming
(*{0.0282592,Null}*)

s4 = BlockDiagonalMatrix@matrices; // RepeatedTiming
(* {0.0281052,Null}*)

s3 == s4
(* True *)
```

Answer (score 0):

Your `ArrayFlatten` method can be made as fast as the other methods with two small tweaks: applying `SparseArray` to the list of dense matrices rather than at the end, and using `N` on the diagonal matrix to turn the off-diagonal zeros into approximate reals.

```
matrices = RandomReal[{}, {128, 128}] & /@ Range[48];

mat1 = SparseArray @ ArrayFlatten @ ReleaseHold @ DiagonalMatrix[Hold /@ matrices]; // RepeatedTiming
(* {3.72, Null} *)

mat2 = ArrayFlatten @ ReleaseHold @ N@DiagonalMatrix[Hold /@ SparseArray@matrices]; // RepeatedTiming
(* {0.045, Null} *)

mat1 == mat2
(* True *)
```